# "feel the urge" vs "have the urge"

Tags: grammar

Which of the following options is correct/would you chose?

"I have the urge to say something" or"I feel the urge to say something"?

Answer (score 1):

Both totally fine.

EDIT to expand original ...

I think **Have** seems subtlety stronger than  **feel** and perhaps more likely to be acted upon. **Feel** seems to be slightly more noncommittal regarding whether the person will '*obey*' those urges.

Comment: My question is a little different, would it be "I can never stop an urge to laugh" OR "I can never stop the urge to laugh". Which article is more natural and why or can both be used?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options are correct.

However, as a native English speaker, it seems that "***have the urge** to say something*" implies that you have had this urge for some time, while ***feel the urge*** to say something" implies that you have only just got the urge.

But they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer, as has been said, is that both phrases are acceptable and used by English speakers frequently.
However, what other answers have not contended is *which one would you choose*. To answer this I have used [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+the+urge%2C+have+the+urge&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20the%20urge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20urge%3B%2Cc0) to analyse the usage of the two phrases.

[image: Google Ngrams analysis; 'feel the urge' is used more than 'have the urge']

As is shown above, the phrase '*feel the urge*' is almost twice as common as '*have the urge*'.
This also chimes with my personal opinion which is that 'feeling' is more appropriate and gives more detail than just 'having' an urge.